# How to create a sub-zip based on the contents of another zip?

Tags: linux, bash, zip

I would like to create a zip that contains just a subset based on another zip file. Is there a smarter way to do this than just extracting the specific files and then re-zipping them under a new name?

I'm looking for an efficient way to do this, as the original file will contain thousands and thousands of files and will have a rough size of ~30 GB.

Comment: One can do it by parsing the (binary) table of content in the .zip file manually. It is located at the end of the file, and contains file name, data offset, compression method, etc. Once you have the table, you can copy only the data you need, and append new table of content. But I've never seen ready-to-use tools (or libraries) which could do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by deleting other stuff e.g.:

```
  zip --delete file.zip junk/*
```

Second option is by listing zip file with

```
 zipinfo -1 file.zip >list.files
```

and edit temporally file list to include. Then you

```
 unzip file.zip $(cat list.files)
```

and create new zip file. Of course the same file can be used for exclusion for `zip --delete`. Or you can do the same using its on the fly file list in combination with `grep` for instance.

Check also https://bitbucket.org/agalanin/fuse-zip

Comment: I'd ended up doing it the second way! Thanks! :)